# Does the sequence $(\frac{sin(k)+k^2}{\root\of{1+3k^4}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge with respect to a distance $d$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Does the sequence $(\frac{sin(k)+k^2}{\root\of{1+3k^4}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge with respect to a distance $d(x, y) = \lvert\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\rvert$ where $d$ is a distance on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

---

This is my answer so far but I am not very confident in it.

$\frac{\root\of{1+3k^4}}{\sin(k)+k^2} \leq \frac{\root\of{1+3k^4}}{-1+k^2} \forall k \geq 2$ , since $\sin(k) \geq -1$.

We also know that the max value of $\frac{\root\of{1+3k^4}}{-1+k^2} = \frac{7}{3} \implies \frac{\root\of{1+3k^4}}{-1+k^2} \leq \frac{7}{3}$

But after this I am not sure how to proceed. Could anyone explain how to proceed next if my logic so far is correct otherwise could you please tell me where it is flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence converges to $1/\sqrt{3}$ in the standard metric (PROVE THIS). Since the terms $a_k$ converge to $a = 1/\sqrt{3}$ (in the standard metric), the terms $1/a_k$ converge to $1/a = \sqrt{3}$ in the standard metric. In the other words, $|1/a_k - 1/ a|$ goes to $0$. Luckily, this is the definition of the convergence of $a_k$ in your metric.

Comment: $1$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$?

Comment: @rtybase $1/\sqrt{3}$, of course:)

Comment: Better, upvoting ;)

Comment: @Antoine Could i use the same argument to show that $(n^2+n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ diverges with respect to the distance $d$.

Comment: @user372834 I think so, yes.